# Apache mod QOS is blocking all users when it should only block per IP

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, botnet

I am running Apache web server on Ubuntu. I am trying to reduce the load on the server due to aggressive bot traffic. Thus I am trying to make use of Apache's mod QOS (http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/index.html) to create a rate limiter for aggressive users.

I've configured it with this:

```
<IfModule mod_qos.c>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/ LimitHits
    QS_ClientEventLimitCount 100 100 LimitHits
    QS_ErrorResponseCode  429
</IfModule>
```

This blocks a user if they exceed 100 requests in 100 seconds.

The problem, though, is that this configuration, for some unknown reason, blocks **all** users when any user crosses the threshold.

It is odd, because this specific variable is shown in the docs to be tied to a requestor's IP, which is exactly what I am trying to do.

> QS_ClientEventLimitCount:
> Defines the maximum number of requests having the defined environment variables
> (QS_Limit by default) set allowed within the defined time (default is
> 600 seconds). Requests from client IP's reaching this limitation are
> denied for the specified time (blocked at request level).

The access logs do show the client IP of each request so I know that these IPs are coming through to Apache.

How can I get the variable **QS_ClientEventLimitCount** to behave as expected and only count requests and block on a per-IP basis?